# What does msg.sender call from a function called from another function return?

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs

I have written a solidity contract which looks something like this:

```
function A(){
       a = B();
}
```

And `B()` is defined as:

```
function B() returns(address){
       return msg.sender;
}
```

I am getting a random string instead of the address of the sender as the output of `a`. Is it because it is called by a function and not by a user?

Comment: Where do you return the 'a' var?

Comment: @PaoloGuerra sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question. The variable `a` is stored in the contract and is called using a get function.

Comment: Yeh, as @BadrBellaj says your code is ok, I just recommend adding constant in functions that do not change the state of variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nothing wrong with your code, I've checked the contract below :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

 contract test {

address public a;
function A(){
       a = B();
}

function B() returns(address){
       return msg.sender;
}
}
```

the variable a gets the sender's address.

[image]